# Laravel 4: Return field from related table within Model function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a table 'sits' and it has `user_id` and `sitter_id` columns.

Inside of my User model, I have the following functions that all work perfectly and return almost everything I need.

```
public function mySits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Sit', 'sitter_id');
}

public function openSits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Sit')->where('sitter_id', '=', '0');
}
```

They work perfectly and returns almost everything I need. I say almost because what I need to do is reference the `users` table to get the name of the Sitter.

In the `sits` table, the `sitter_id` maps to `id` in the `users` table which has a name field.

Can I add something to the `return` data in the User model methods, or would I need do something in my controller.

```
$user = User::find(1)->load('mySits', 'openSits');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `User` relationship inside your `Sit` model. Then access it via `$sit->user->name` or similar.